# R how to sum 2 measurements from the same experimental unit on different dates

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a database of coral recruitment to experimental units or modules.  During one of my censuses, I had to start and complete recruit censuses on different days for the North (N) side of module 114.  I need to sum the number of recruits for these instances while using the last observation date as the Date. In the case of rows 1 and 2, I want the date for the combined row to be 2017-08-20.

I needed to use the complete function to populate implicitly missing data where no recruits were observed.  However, this creates an issue because the data frame includes multiple rows (observations) when for analysis, I need 1 row.

```
n3 <- structure(list(`Module #` = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("111", "112", 
"113", "114", "115", "116", "211", "212", "213", "214", "215", 
"216"), class = "factor"), Side = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("N", 
"S", "T"), class = "factor"), TimeStep = c(4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), Date = structure(c(17389, 
17398, 17482, 17601, NA, 17389, 17404, NA, 17601, 17682, 17389, 
17404, NA, 17601, NA), class = "Date"), Year = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("17", 
"18"), class = "factor"), Site = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
NA, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, NA), .Label = c("HAN", 
"WAI"), class = "factor"), Treatment = c("CLO", "CLO", "CLO", 
"CLO", NA, "CLO", "CLO", NA, "CLO", "CLO", "CLO", "CLO", NA, 
"CLO", NA), recruits = c(5, 1, 2, 1, 0, 4, 1, 0, 2, 4, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0), Site_long = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Hanauma Bay", "Waikiki"
), class = "factor"), Shelter = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("High", "Low"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```

My output should be 12 rows by combining rows 1-2, 6-7, and 11-12.  Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Get max `Date` value and `sum` the recruits in each group and select only 1 row from each of them.

```
library(dplyr)

n3 %>%
  group_by(`Module #`, Side, TimeStep) %>%
  mutate(Date = max(Date, na.rm = TRUE), 
         recruits = sum(recruits)) %>%
  slice(1)

# `Module #` Side  TimeStep Date       Year  Site  Treatment recruits Site_long Shelter
#   <fct>      <fct>    <int> <date>     <fct> <fct> <chr>        <dbl> <fct>     <fct>  
# 1 114        N            4 2017-08-20 17    WAI   CLO              6 Waikiki   Low    
# 2 114        N            5 2017-11-12 17    WAI   CLO              2 Waikiki   Low    
# 3 114        N            6 2018-03-11 18    WAI   CLO              1 Waikiki   Low    
# 4 114        N            7 NA         18    NA    NA               0 Waikiki   Low    
# 5 114        S            4 2017-08-26 17    WAI   CLO              5 Waikiki   Low    
# 6 114        S            5 NA         17    NA    NA               0 Waikiki   Low    
# 7 114        S            6 2018-03-11 18    WAI   CLO              2 Waikiki   Low    
# 8 114        S            7 2018-05-31 18    WAI   CLO              4 Waikiki   Low    
# 9 114        T            4 2017-08-26 17    WAI   CLO              2 Waikiki   Low    
#10 114        T            5 NA         17    NA    NA               0 Waikiki   Low    
#11 114        T            6 2018-03-11 18    WAI   CLO              1 Waikiki   Low    
#12 114        T            7 NA         18    NA    NA               0 Waikiki   Low
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table` methods.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(n3)`), grouped by 'Module #', 'Side', 'TimeStep', get the `max` of 'Date' and `sum` of 'recruits', update those columns and get the `unique` rows by those grouping variables

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(n3)[,  c("Date", "recruits") :=  list(max(Date, 
  na.rm = TRUE),  sum(recruits)), .(`Module #`, Side, TimeStep)],
         by = c("Module #", "Side", "TimeStep"))
#  Module # Side TimeStep       Date Year Site Treatment recruits Site_long Shelter
# 1:      114    N        4 2017-08-20   17  WAI       CLO       24   Waikiki     Low
# 2:      114    N        5 2017-11-12   17  WAI       CLO        2   Waikiki     Low
# 3:      114    N        6 2018-03-11   18  WAI       CLO        1   Waikiki     Low
# 4:      114    N        7       <NA>   18 <NA>      <NA>        0   Waikiki     Low
# 5:      114    S        4 2017-08-26   17  WAI       CLO       20   Waikiki     Low
# 6:      114    S        5       <NA>   17 <NA>      <NA>        0   Waikiki     Low
# 7:      114    S        6 2018-03-11   18  WAI       CLO        2   Waikiki     Low
# 8:      114    S        7 2018-05-31   18  WAI       CLO        4   Waikiki     Low
# 9:      114    T        4 2017-08-26   17  WAI       CLO        8   Waikiki     Low
#10:      114    T        5       <NA>   17 <NA>      <NA>        0   Waikiki     Low
#11:      114    T        6 2018-03-11   18  WAI       CLO        1   Waikiki     Low
#12:      114    T        7       <NA>   18 <NA>      <NA>        0   Waikiki     Low
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`, we `arrange` by the first 4 columns, grouped by the 'Module #', 'Side', 'TimeStep', `mutate` to get the `sum` of 'recruits' and `slice` the last row

```
library(tidyverse)
n3 %>%
   arrange_at(1:4) %>% 
   group_by_at(1:3) %>% 
   mutate(recruits = sum(recruits)) %>%
   slice(n())
# A tibble: 12 x 10
# Groups:   Module #, Side, TimeStep [12]
#   `Module #` Side  TimeStep Date       Year  Site  Treatment recruits Site_long Shelter
#   <fct>      <fct>    <int> <date>     <fct> <fct> <chr>        <dbl> <fct>     <fct>  
# 1 114        N            4 2017-08-20 17    WAI   CLO              6 Waikiki   Low    
# 2 114        N            5 2017-11-12 17    WAI   CLO              2 Waikiki   Low    
# 3 114        N            6 2018-03-11 18    WAI   CLO              1 Waikiki   Low    
# 4 114        N            7 NA         18    <NA>  <NA>             0 Waikiki   Low    
# 5 114        S            4 2017-08-26 17    WAI   CLO              5 Waikiki   Low    
# 6 114        S            5 NA         17    <NA>  <NA>             0 Waikiki   Low    
# 7 114        S            6 2018-03-11 18    WAI   CLO              2 Waikiki   Low    
# 8 114        S            7 2018-05-31 18    WAI   CLO              4 Waikiki   Low    
# 9 114        T            4 2017-08-26 17    WAI   CLO              2 Waikiki   Low    
#10 114        T            5 NA         17    <NA>  <NA>             0 Waikiki   Low    
#11 114        T            6 2018-03-11 18    WAI   CLO              1 Waikiki   Low    
#12 114        T            7 NA         18    <NA>  <NA>             0 Waikiki   Low
```

Comment: akrun thank you so much this code solved the problem!  I ended up altering your code slightly to refer to the column names by name instead of indexed.  Again thank you and for those who are looking at this, here is my final code:

Comment: ```{r}
n3 %>%
   arrange((Date)) %>% 
   group_by(`Module #`, Side, TimeStep) %>% 
   mutate(recruits = sum(recruits)) %>%
   slice(n())
```